# Loading Employee table using SSIS (Flat file to SQLServer)

Tags: ssis

As this is more common task, would like to check the best practices while loading the employee table.

Employee table has ManagerID, which is a FK for the same table.

Input File:
Employee ID with all other info
Manager's Last Name
Manager's First Name

Target Table:
EmployeeID
All other employee Info
Manager's ID (FK to EmployeeID)

Is there any way to lookup EmployeeID of the manager during the translation?  If not, what is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LookUp component to find the Manager Id foreign key based on fields in your source file.  This will execute an individual request back to you database to match the details you supply regarding the manager.

[image]

You can then configure the LookUp command to manage missing details (i.e. no match) accordingly within the component.

Alternatively, if the volume of data is too large for multiple lookup calls, you can stage the table "as is" and create a second data flow task to perform the join within a sql select statement.  Then use the result of this second flow to populate your main employee table.  This will result in more effort from a ssis and table creation perspective, but will be quicker for data of any volume